# How to login using UserName or Email in ASP.NET in Identity 2?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, the application scafolded an authentication but the login only authenticates/logins users using the UserName. How to edit the login method to accept either email or username?

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be as simple as making the UserName and Email the same. As in store the Email in the UserName field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's as simple as making the `UserName` and `Email` the same. As in store the Email in the UserName field.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with making and additional call to the database in the case of it being an email address, here is an example of what you can try.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Signin(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        string username = model.UserName;
        ApplicationUser user = null;
        // CHECK FOR EMAIL
        if(IsValidEmail(username)) {
            user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(username);
            if(user != null) username = user.UserName;
            else {
                // If user with email address does not exists, here is a good place
                // to exit as we have already ascertained that the user is not in the system
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid user name or password provided.") 
                return View(model); 
            }                
        }
        // END CHECK FOR EMAIL
        user = await userManager.FindAsync(username, model.Password);
        if (user != null) {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            .....
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid user name or password provided.") 
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, re-display form
    return View(model);
}

private static bool IsValidEmail(string email) {
    string MatchEmailPattern =
       @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@" +
       @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\." +
       @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|" +
       @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

    if (!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)) {
        string pattern = MatchEmailPattern;
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(email, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```